# Convergent vs. Divergent Sequences of same power quotient

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Alright, so a new topic in math for me, sequences. I'm suppose to prove if the converge or diverge. I'm not to sure how to do this, but i'm gonna put out what I have and see how wrong I am about this.
$${(n-1)(3n+1)^3\over (n-2)^4}$$

So I expanded my equation out and got $${27n^4-18n^2-8n-1\over n^4-8n^3+24n^2+16n+16}$$

So if I took the limit it would be 27 cause of having the same power on both denominator and numerator. However this is not a proof of it converging. How would I use an arbitray epsilon to proves this? My understanding is to use my equation -1. and find an epislon from there, but I can't seem to do it and the book isn't of much help

EDIT: Made a mistake in the writing the equation

$$n*{28n^3+8n^2-36n-24+}{-17\over n }*{1\over n^4-8n^3+24n^2+16n+16 }$$ is what I got by subtracting my equation by 1

Comment: It depend on the tools to which you have access.  Are you required to do this *directly* from the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit?  Or can you use some of the calculus of limits, i.e. results like "under appropriate hypotheses, $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{\lim a_n}{\lim b_n}$"?  Also, how did you end up with a quartic in the denominator?  It is linear in your first expression...

Comment: It doesn't say epsilon directly specifically, but thats what we have been learning.

Comment: Okay... so what have you done?  Surely you've written down something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Claim:** We have
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4} = 27.$$

*Proof:*  In order to prove this, we must show that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N > 0$ such that
$$ \left| \frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4} - 27 \right| < \varepsilon $$
for any $n \ge N$.  So, begin by fixing some $\varepsilon > 0$.  Then (with a bit of help from WolframAlpha to expedite the tedious computations)

\begin{align}
\left| \frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4} - 27 \right|
&= \left| \frac{(27n^4 - 18n^2 - 8n - 1) - 27(n^4 - 8n^3 + 24n^2 + 16n + 16)}{n^4 - 8 n^3 + 24 n^2 - 32 n + 16} \right| \\
&= \left| \frac{216 n^3 - 666 n^2 + 856 n - 433}{n^4 - 8 n^3 + 24 n^2 - 32 n + 16} \right| \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left| \frac{216 - 666 \frac{1}{n} + 856 \frac{1}{n^2} - 433\frac{1}{n^3}}{ 1 - 8 \frac{1}{n} + 24 \frac{1}{n^2} - 32 \frac{1}{n^3} + 16 \frac{1}{n^4}} \right|.
\end{align}
By choosing $n$ large enough, we can ensure that
$$ \left| 1 - 8 \frac{1}{n} + 24 \frac{1}{n^2} - 32 \frac{1}{n^3} + 16 \frac{1}{n^4} \right| > \frac{1}{2}; $$
indeed, via the tried-and-true method of guess-and-check (with a little help from our friend WolframAlpha) $n > 13$ seems to get the job done.  This implies that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n} \left| \frac{216 - 666 \frac{1}{n} + 856 \frac{1}{n^2} - 433\frac{1}{n^3}}{ 1 - 8 \frac{1}{n} + 24 \frac{1}{n^2} - 32 \frac{1}{n^3} + 16 \frac{1}{n^4}} \right|
&< \frac{2}{n} \left|  216 - 666 \frac{1}{n} + 856 \frac{1}{n^2} - 433\frac{1}{n^3} \right| \\
&\le \frac{2}{n} \left( 216 + 666\frac{1}{n} + 856 \frac{1}{n^2} + 433 \frac{1}{n^3} \right).
\end{align}
In this last inequality, we are using the triangle inequality and the fact that $n > 0$ in order to obtain the result.  Again, we can pick $n$ large enough to get a somewhat sloppy estimate.  Indeed, if $n > 666$, then $\frac{666}{n} < 1$, $\frac{856}{n^2} < 1$, and $\frac{433}{n^3} < 1$.  Thus, with this very sloppy estimate, we have
$$ \frac{2}{n} \left( 216 + 666\frac{1}{n} + 856 \frac{1}{n^2} + 433 \frac{1}{n^3} \right)
< \frac{2}{n} \left( 216 + 1 + 1 + 1 \right)
= \frac{438}{n}.
$$
Finally, if $n > 438\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$, we get
$$
\frac{438}{n} < \frac{438}{438 \frac{1}{\varepsilon}} = \varepsilon. $$
Therefore if we take $N \ge \max\left\{13, 666, 438\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \right\}$, then for any $n \ge N$, we have
$$ \left| \frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4} - 27 \right| < \varepsilon, $$
which gives the desired result.

---

Note that there are *better* ways of doing this.  Typically, you want to prove two results:

> **Lemma:** We have
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0. $$

You should be able to prove this without too much difficulty.

> **Lemma:** Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = A$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = B$.  Then
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n + b_n) = A+B. $$
>   Moreover, if $B \ne 0$, then
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{A}{B}. $$

The proof of the first identity is pretty straight-forward.  The second is a little more delicate, but also very doable.  You should perhaps go through the details of each—they are good exercises.  Once these results are established, we have
\begin{align} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4}
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{27n^4 - 18n^2 - 8n - 1}{n^4 - 8 n^3 + 24 n^2 - 32 n + 16} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{27 - \frac{18}{n^2} - \frac{8}{n^3} - \frac{1}{n^4} }{1 - \frac{8}{n} + \frac{24}{n^2} - \frac{32}{n^3} + \frac{16}{n^4} } && \left(\text{multiply by $\frac{1/n^4}{1/n^4} = 1$}\right) \\
&= \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 27 - \frac{18}{n^2} - \frac{8}{n^3} - \frac{1}{n^4} \right) }{\lim_{n\to\infty}  \left( 1 - \frac{8}{n} + \frac{24}{n^2} - \frac{32}{n^3} + \frac{16}{n^4} \right) }.
\end{align}
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}$, most of the terms in the numerator and denominator go to zero.  Thus
$$ \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 27 - \frac{18}{n^2} - \frac{8}{n^3} - \frac{1}{n^4} \right) }{\lim_{n\to\infty}  \left( 1 - \frac{8}{n} + \frac{24}{n^2} - \frac{32}{n^3} + \frac{16}{n^4} \right) }
= \frac{27 + 0 + 0 + 0}{1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0} = 27.$$

Answer (score 0):

A better approach that would still allow $\epsilon$-proofs would be to use upper and lower bounds that are easier to work with and then apply the squeeze theorem. Remember that in order to make a positive fraction larger we can either increase the numerator or decrease the denominator.

For instance, 
$$\frac{(n-1)(3n)^3}{n^4} <\frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4} < \frac{(n)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4}$$

**Reasoning the upcoming step**:
Now I'm not a big fan of terms like $(n-1)$ in the above expression, because I know it will make an $\epsilon$ proof a bit messy. We get the same problem with $3n+1$; we could bound it above by $3n+3=3(n+1)$, but then we have to deal with $(n+1)$. I want these expressions in terms of a power of $n$ and maybe some constant multipliers as well. With that in mind:

Fix some $\eta>0$, then for $n$ large enough ($n> N_1$), $$n-1 > n-\eta\cdot n = n(1-\eta)$$
also for $n$ large enough ($n>N_2$),
$$3n+1 < 3n+n\cdot 3\eta = 3n(1+\eta)$$
and finally for $n$ large enough ($n>N_3$),
$$n-2 > n-\eta\cdot n = n(1-\eta)$$
So if $n>\max\{N_1,N_2,N_3\}$,
$$\frac{\big(n(1-\eta)\big)(3n)^3}{n^4} <\frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4} < \frac{(n)\big(3n(1+\eta)\big)^3}{\big(n(1-\eta)\big)^4}$$
so the squeeze theorem gives
$$27(1-\eta) \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^4}{n^4} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4} \leq 27 \frac{(1+\eta)^3}{(1-\eta)^4} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^4}{n^4}$$
and an utterly trivial $\epsilon$ proof (that I'll leave to you) shows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^4}{n^4} = 1$. Hence
$$27(1-\eta) \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4} \leq 27 \frac{(1+\eta)^3}{(1-\eta)^4}$$

But $\eta>0$ was arbitrary, so letting $\eta \to 0^+$ gives
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4} = 27$$